# Resizing vue-chartjs height while keeping it responsive

Tags: vue.js, chart.js, resize, height, vue-chartjs

**Need help with chart js**

ACTUALLY, I'M USING VUE-CHARTJS BUT IT'S JUST A WRAPPER

in the line chart on the left side, the number is increasing by 5(0, 5, 10, 15, etc) I want it to increase by 10 and also decrease the height of the chart so the aspect ratio is something like 16/9
[image]

also is it possible to make the left number say 5k+, 10k+, 15k+ instead of just 5, 10, 15

here's my code for the chart

```html
<script>
import { Line } from 'vue-chartjs'

export default {
  extends: Line,
  data: () => ({
    chartdata: {
    labels: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May','Jun'],
    datasets: [
        {
            data: [12, 20, 27, 22, 14, 10],
            borderColor: "#135193",
            pointBackgroundColor: "#135193",
            pointBorderColor: "#135193",
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)'
        },
        {
            data: [3, 12, 17, 20, 30, 40],
            borderColor: "#FF8811",
            pointBackgroundColor: "#FF8811",
            pointBorderColor: "#FF8811",
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)'
        }
    ]
    },
    options: {
      responsive: true,
      legend: {
        display: false
      }
    }
  }),

  mounted () {
    this.renderChart(this.chartdata, this.options)
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can just use CSS to set the dimensions of the canvas and set `maintainAspectRatio` to `false` in the options, for the ticks you can use the tick callback:

```js
const labels = ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"];

const options = {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels,
    datasets: [{
      label: '# of Votes',
      data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
      borderColor: 'red',
      backgroundColor: 'pink'
    }]
  },
  options: {
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          callback: (val) => (`${val}K`)
        }
      }]
    }
  }
}

const ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```css
canvas {
  max-height: 180px;
  max-width: 320px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.4/Chart.js"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay it turns out its as simple as wrapping the chart with a container and set height of that container as needed